# Создание виртуального окружения в python

Tags: python

Работаю на windows. Почему внутри виртуального окружения не создается директория Scripts. Почему создается папка bin? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А это как-то мешает? Вирт пространство нормально себя ведет? Плюс смущает `python3`-команда, которая используется в POSIX системах. Если вы не переопределяли `PATH`, то у вас должна отрабатывать команда `py`

Comment: Если вы зайдете в интерпретатор python и введете команды `import sys` и `print(sys.platform)`, какой результат вы получите?

Comment: print(sys.platform) выводит win32

Comment: команда py работает

Comment: вообще странно, так как папки в `__init__` модуля `venv` создаются

Comment: а какое приветствие интерпретатор выдает когда вы в него заходите? Меня интересует конец строки, что то такое `[MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug 15 2021, 14:49:43)  [GCC 10.3.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: почему Python 3.9.6? Я же установил 3.10 версию

Comment: чтобы увидеть откуда берется python используйте команды `where py`, `where python`, `where python3`. После того как убедитесь, что то идет не так начните с определения команд в `PATH` windows